# If Function with multiple conditions. IFS does

Tags: excel

I have a column of numbers. I need to return values of "Below" if my number is less than 30, "within" if my number is between 30 and 150, and "above" if my number is above 150. How do I go about writing this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

[image]

The formula I've used in B1 is:

```
=IF(A1<30;"Below";IF(A1>150;"Above";"Within"))
```

Drag down and done!